# printf flags are not displaying correctly?

Tags: java, printf

My AP book says that if you put the "$" before the % it will output whatever the value with the "$" before it, this from what I understand is referred to as flags. Yet when I was doing this I got something differently for instance:

```
public void printResults(){
    System.out.printf("%10s %10s %10s \n", "Item:", "Cost:", "Price:");
    System.out.printf("%10d $%10.2f %10.2f \n", n++ ,productOne, productOne);
    System.out.printf("%10d $%10.2f %10.2f \n", n++ ,productTwo, productTwo+=productOne);
    System.out.printf("%10d $%10.2f %10.2f", n++ ,productThree, productThree+=productTwo);
}
```

this outputted:

```
 Item:      Cost:     Price: 
     1 $      5.00       5.00 
     2 $      5.00      10.00 
     3 $      5.00      15.00
```

instead of:

```
 Item:      Cost:     Price: 
     1       $5.00       5.00 
     2       $5.00      10.00 
     3       $5.00      15.00
```

Why is the "$" going so many characters to the left when it supposedly was supposed to be at the beginning of each one of my values?

Answer (score 0):

Because this

```
"%10d $%10.2f
```

means to use up 10 characters for a number (with the number at the right of the 10 columns)

then put a space and a dollar sign

then use up 10 more characters for another number with 2 digits after a decimal point and the number pushed to the right.

If you want the dollar sign right beside the number, you will have to either use

```
String one = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(productOne);
System.out.printf("%10d %11s %10.2f \n", n++ ,one, productOne);
```

or format the number some other way, like, perhaps

```
String one = "$" + productOne; // this won't do exactly 2 fractional digits.
```

There are other ways.

Answer (score 0):

You specified a total length of `10` when your format said: `%10.2f`, and your `$` character was before the formatted number.  So you got

```
"$" + "      5.00"
```

You can use a `DecimalFormat` to work around this issue:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("$#.00");
String s = df.format(productOne);
```

and later

```
System.out.printf("%10s \n");
```

Output:

```
     $5.00
```